# R custom ordering of character vector by matching the first character

Tags: r

I'm trying to sort a vector in R.

This is an example of how the vector looks like:

```
test = c("Xpsomethingelse", "3qsometext", "22qsomeothertext")
```

Simple sorting results in:

```
> sort(test)
[1] "22qsomeothertext" "3qsometext"       "Xpsomethingelse"
```

However I want to sort in a custom order, based on the first/second character of each string. I have created another vector that represents the order that should be followed

```
order_custom = c("21","18","13","X","Y","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","14","15","16","17","19","20","22")
```

I thought of

```
test[order(match(test, order_custom))]
```

But this only matches the complete string, while I'm looking for a match with the start of the string. Everything before the 'p' or 'q' character should be taken into account. The match in regex terms should be this [0-9,X,Y]{1,2} I think. But I don't see how I can sort based on this type of match.

The final result should look like this

```
[1] "Xpsomethingelse", "3qsometext", "22qsomeothertext"
```

Comment: The problem is that some string ("Xpsomethingelse") must be matched on the first character, while others ("22qsomeothertext") on the first two. Is there some rule to be followed, like "match on the first character if the second is a letter, match on the first 2 if the second character is a number"? If so, then it should be possible to accomplish what you want playing with regex.

Comment: @GKi because you need to match 22 & not 2. You should match everything that occurs before character [p,q]

Comment: @Claudio yes. Basically it's a match to everything that occurs before the character 'p' or 'q'. I've added this clarification now to the question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub` to remove p or q and everything afterwards and then use `match` and `order`.

```
test[order(match(sub("[pq].*", "", test), order_custom))]
#[1] "Xpsomethingelse"  "3qsometext"       "22qsomeothertext"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your original code providing a regular expressions to match whatever comes before a "p" or a "q":

```r
library(stringi)

test = c("Xpsomethingelse", "3qsometext", "22qsomeothertext")

order_custom = c("21","18","13","X","Y","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","14","15","16","17","19","20","22")

test[order(match(stri_extract(test, regex=".+(?=[p|q])"), order_custom))]
#> [1] "Xpsomethingelse"  "3qsometext"       "22qsomeothertext"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a intutional solution to sort by the rank of `h3`.

```r
library(data.table)
test = c("22qsomeothertext", "3qsometext", "Xpsomethingelse")
order_custom = c("21","18","13","X","Y","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","14","15","16","17","19","20","22")

dt <- data.table(test)
dt[,`:=`(h1 = substr(test,1,1),
         h2 = substr(test,1,2)) ]

dt[,h3 := fcase(h1 %in% order_custom & !(h2 %in% order_custom), h1,
                h1 %in% order_custom & (h1 %in% order_custom), h2,
                default = NA)]

dt[,rank := match(h3, order_custom)][]
#>                test h1 h2 h3 rank
#> 1: 22qsomeothertext  2 22 22   24
#> 2:       3qsometext  3 3q  3    8
#> 3:  Xpsomethingelse  X Xp  X    4

desired_string <-  dt[order(rank),test]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>